# format list of synopsis for a custom list of functions

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script containing several functions representing tasks. I would like to format a list of those functions with for each function its name and the synopsis provided in the documentation.

For one function Foo:

`Get-Help  Foo | Format-Table -Property Name, Synopsis`

I don't know how to make it work with multiple functions. I am having troubles with the power syntax. I don't know how to declare a list of function because `Foo, Bar` is a syntax error. I also tried to list the names of the function as strings and convert those to the corresponding objects but I failed to do so.

How to print the name and synopsis for a custom list of functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you figured out yourself, the [Get-Help](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113316) (alias `help`) cmdlet doesnt expose a parameter set with multiple `-name` parameters. However, You can define an *array* of your functions, iterate over it and call the `Get-Help` for each of them. Example:

```
@('Get-Content', 'Get-ChildItem') | foreach { help $_ }  | Format-Table -Property Name, Synopsis
```

*Output:*

```
Name          Synopsis                                                          
----          --------                                                          
Get-Content   Gets the content of the item at the specified location.           
Get-ChildItem Gets the items and child items in one or more specified locations.
```

Comment: @('Get-Content', 'Get-ChildItem') | foreach { Get-Help $_ } | Format-Table -Property Name, Synopsis is what I was looking for (to get only one table). Thank you!